# How to get phrase tables from word alignments?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, machine-translation, moses

The output of my word alignment file looks as such:

```
I wish to say with regard to the initiative of the Portuguese Presidency that we support the spirit and the political intention behind it . In bezug auf die Initiative der portugiesischen Präsidentschaft möchte ich zum Ausdruck bringen , daß wir den Geist und die politische Absicht , die dahinter stehen , unterstützen .   0-0 5-1 5-2 2-3 8-4 7-5 11-6 12-7 1-8 0-9 9-10 3-11 10-12 13-13 13-14 14-15 16-16 17-17 18-18 16-19 20-20 21-21 19-22 19-23 22-24 22-25 23-26 15-27 24-28
It may not be an ideal initiative in terms of its structure but we accept Mr President-in-Office , that it is rooted in idealism and for that reason we are inclined to support it .    Von der Struktur her ist es vielleicht keine ideale Initiative , aber , Herr amtierender Ratspräsident , wir akzeptieren , daß sie auf Idealismus fußt , und sind deshalb geneigt , sie mitzutragen .   0-0 11-2 8-3 0-4 3-5 1-6 2-7 5-8 6-9 12-11 17-12 15-13 16-14 16-15 17-16 13-17 14-18 17-19 18-20 19-21 21-22 23-23 21-24 26-25 24-26 29-27 27-28 30-29 31-30 33-31 32-32 34-33
```

How can I produce the phrase tables that are used by MOSES from this output?

In this pdf, it explains the `consistent phrase` extraction: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mt/lectures/phrase-model.pdf but **what is the algorithm to achieve the phrases**? (slide 16-21)

Comment: i've tried iterating all possible sizes of cells with all possible combination. but that will give me `n! * m! * n * m` cells to check through for every sentence, where n and m are length of the source and target sentence.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to get the alignment itself? How does your alignment work?

Comment: @Daniel, word alignment != phrase table. I've found the algorithm but it's not working somehow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109001/phrase-extraction-algorithm-for-statistical-machine-translation

Comment: What do you mean by "not working somehow"? You implemented the algorithm below in the response, and it is giving wrong answers?

Comment: yes, it's not giving the right output...

Comment: well, it seems like the alignment below is just an approximation, and not guaranteed to give consistent results.

Comment: Is this a standard input format? Looks pretty ad-hoc and hard to use.

Comment: yes, it's the pharaoh output format. One could also prefer the giza output format though, e.g. http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/?q=en/node/1325#ali.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get a phrase table is to first extract the phrase table with the following algorithm from Philip Koehn's Statistical MT book, pp. 133:

[image]

Then estimate the probabilities for the phrases with their relative frequencies, i.e.

[image]

Note that there is an error in the original printed version of the book but it's addressed in the errata on line 4 of the `extract()` function.

Also see [Phrase extraction algorithm for statistical machine translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109001/phrase-extraction-algorithm-for-statistical-machine-translation) for the details.